# Fractional Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

In Mandelbrot(1968)'s paper, the fractional brownian motion, denoted by $B_{H}(t,\omega)$,(t>0) is defined by 
$$B_{H}(0,\omega)=b_{0}$$
$$B_{H}(t,\omega)-B_{H}(0,\omega)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(H+\frac{1}{2})}\{\int^{0}_{-\infty}[(t-s)^{H-1/2}-(-s)^{H-1/2}]dB(s,\omega)+\int^{t}_{0}(t-s)^{H-1/2}dB(s,\omega)\}$$
I have difficulty understanding fractional brownian motion by self study.Is there an intuitive interpretation of this definition? Why time s can have negative value? Thanks!

Comment: Why should $s$ be negative?

Comment: I mean that the lower bound of the first integral on the right hand side is negative infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more phenomenological definitions in his books are probably more helpful. Whether one uses the fractal dimension, Hurst coefficient, or exponential coefficient alpha, there is a value that corresponds to pure Brownian motion, a regime relative to this value that corresponds to persistence of motion, and the opposite regime that corresponds to anti-persistence of motion. Mandelbrot's book The (Mis)behaviour of Markets gives several good examples.

Only the pure Brownian motion regime doesn't depend on the past. You don't define any variables, but I'd guess Mandelbrot is using the Hurst coefficient in the equation you give, where pure Brownian motion is H = 0.5. In this case the first integral gives 1 - 1, i.e. no dependence on the past (times leading up to time 0, i.e. "negative" time). For other cases (0 <= H <= 1, H != 0.5), the process leading up to time zero, and continuing on until time $t$, each incremental step in the process does depend on the previous steps.

Answer (score 6):

For a Brownian motion, if you wait $dt$, the variance will grow linearly with (proportionally to) $dt$.

For a fractional Brownian motion, it will grow with a power law of $dt$, in fact in $dt^{H}$, where $H$ is the **Hurst exponent**. See [wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurst_exponent) for more details.

It means the fBM will somehow keep **memory** of the past. When $H$ is lower than 1/2, it will *mean revert*, when it is greater than 1/2, it will be *superdiffusive*. At $H$, it is a Brownian motion.

This paper [Volatility is rough](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3394) by Gatheral, Jasson and Rosenbaum gives a good idea of how to use properties of fBM in financial modelling.